# [ubuntu]reinstall apache2 and can not access to my wordpress

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

my wordpress folder is in the /var/www/html/

so the first time I want to locate the domain name to /var/www/html/wordpress but I lost the css, and I don't know why.

Then I found some files of apaches deleted by me so I tried to reinstall apache2 by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
whereis apache2
```

Then I delete all the files concerned with `whereis apache2` and `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Then the question is:

when I visit the IP address of my vps, chrome tells me that the website is not available, and to the domain name it shows the apache2 ubuntu default page.

So please tell me what should I do right now to fix this?
If there is no way to fix it please tell me how to back my wordpress up.

Thank you.

Comment: You showed you delete the apache install, but did you re-install? Sorry if this sounds like a silly question. Anyway, if you deleted all the files then /var/www/html was possibly deleted as well, so check that it still exists.

Comment: /var/www/html does exist, and also two folders exist too, one is my joomla site folder and another one is the wordpress

Comment: Try calling your site by `http://yourdomain/wp/wp-admin`, as your root site folder's index.php was over-written perhaps by the re-install. It probalby also overwrote the .htaccess file, so you need to get back into wp-admin so you can save your permalinks again which will re-create the correct lines in .htaccess. I say use `/wp/`, but if you installed wordpress into another folder use that foldername instead.

Comment: still not available, I used the right folder and chrome told me that Google Chrome's connection attempt to "my IP address"

Comment: But you said in your question " it shows the apache2 ubuntu default page", so what happened after that? Tthat show it is connecting to your ip address, just not the page you desire. Maybe check your apache2.conf to see if your root folder points somewhere else besides /var/www, and change it if it does.

Comment: thanks, I will check it, also I backup my wordpress folder if there is no way to fix I have to reinstall something..

Comment: Yes, if you reinstall then just restore your backup folder to the one pointed to by the new install, shich should be /var/www/html methinks. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I re-install both apache and php5, and question was solved..

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```